# NSStringDrawingOptions convert value

Tags: ios, swift

I using JSSAlertView from GitHub and I got error with the code after updated Xcode to 7.0
The error is 'Cannot convert value of type '[String : UIFont?]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'
I can't understand what NSFontAttributeName:textView.font did

```
    // Position text
    if self.textView != nil {
        let textString = textView.text! as NSString
        let textAttr = [NSFontAttributeName:textView.font]
        let realSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(contentWidth, CGFloat.max))
        let textSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: CGFloat(fmaxf(Float(90.0), Float(realSize.height))))
       let textRect = textString.boundingRectWithSize(textSize, options: NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: textAttr, context: nil)
        self.textView.frame = CGRect(x: self.padding, y: yPos, width: self.alertWidth - (self.padding*2), height: ceil(textRect.size.height)*2)
        yPos += ceil(textRect.size.height) + padding/2
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSStringDrawingOptions` is a set of options. You have to provide a value, like `NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesFontLeading`.

For more information, see [NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSStringDrawingOptions).

Edit:
To answer your edited question, `textView.font` is an optional. the easiest way to unwrap it is to add an exclamation mark `textView.font!`. But i would prefer conditional binding. Read about optionals [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330).

Comment: I tried but still error Cannot convert value of type '[String : UIFont?]' to expected argument type '[String : AnyObject]?'